# How do you return EQS screens for a particular date using the Bloomberg VBA API?

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I would like, for a given Bloomberg EQS screen, to be able to return the screen results on a given date.

I have been playing around with the Bloomberg file EqsDataExample.xls for a while now, but I have been unable to return anything other than the screen for the current date.

The Bloomberg function used in an Excel sheet is:

```
=BEQS(screen_name,"Asof=" & asof_date,)
```

Below is the function from the example, that I have modified unsuccessfully.  I presume I need to do something with the override functionality, but it's just not there yet.

```
Public Sub MakeRequest(sScreenName As String, sScreenType As String, sGroup As String)

    Dim req As Request
    Dim nRow As Long

    Set req = refdataservice.CreateRequest("BeqsRequest")
    req.Set "screenName", sScreenName
    req.Set "screenType", sScreenType
    'req.Set "Group", sGroup

    ' >> My addition, trying to get the asof date override
    Dim overrides As Element
    Set overrides = req.GetElement("overrides")        
    Dim override  As Element
    Set override = overrides.AppendElment()
    override.SetElement "fieldId", "ASOF="
    override.SetElement "value", "20101130"
    'MsgBox req.Print
    ' <<

    ' The following code is used to request data for a custom field that is setup
    ' using EQS <GO> on the Bloomberg Professional service. To use, uncomment these
    ' next 3 lines of code and comment out the previous 3 lines of code (above)
    ' Set req = refdataservice.CreateRequest("CustomEqsRequest")
    ' req.GetElement("fields").AppendValue "#NameOfCustomField"  ' Add name of custom field with # prefix
    ' req.Append "securities", "IBM US Equity" ' Add name of your security

    ' Add a correlation id
    Dim cid As blpapicomLib2.CorrelationId

    ' Send the request
    Set cid = session.SendRequest(req)

    curRow = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `=`? `override.SetElement "fieldId", "ASOF"`. Also there seems top be a typo in `overrides.AppendElment()` - should probably be `overrides.AppendElement()`

Comment: I did try without the "=" after the 'Asof', and the method is indeed overrides.AppendElment().  Strange choice of spelling from Bloomberg on that.  I figured out the answer...the fieldId should be set to "PiTDate" - I will paste the code that works below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the fieldId to "PiTDate" - I found this in the Bloomberg API documentation.

Here is the code that works:

```
Public Sub MakeRequest(sScreenName As String, sScreenType As String, sGroup As String)

    Dim req As Request
    Dim nRow As Long

    Set req = refdataservice.CreateRequest("BeqsRequest")
    req.Set "screenName", sScreenName
    req.Set "screenType", sScreenType
    'req.Set "Group", sGroup

    ' My Code >>
    Dim overrides As Element
    Set overrides = req.GetElement("overrides")
    Dim override  As Element
    Set override = overrides.AppendElment()
    override.SetElement "fieldId", "PiTDate"
    override.SetElement "value", "20141130"
    'MsgBox req.Print
    ' <<

    ' The following code is used to request data for a custom field that is setup
    ' using EQS <GO> on the Bloomberg Professional service. To use, uncomment these
    ' next 3 lines of code and comment out the previous 3 lines of code (above)
    ' Set req = refdataservice.CreateRequest("CustomEqsRequest")
    ' req.GetElement("fields").AppendValue "#NameOfCustomField"  ' Add name of custom field with # prefix
    ' req.Append "securities", "IBM US Equity" ' Add name of your security

    ' Add a correlation id
    Dim cid As blpapicomLib2.CorrelationId

    ' Send the request
    Set cid = session.SendRequest(req)

    curRow = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a workable solution, you should accept your own answer.